# Select2 load ajax data only once based on previous selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have two dropdowns, one being Countries, the second Cities.

```
<select class="form-control" id="CountryId" name="CountryId"><option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option> 
    <option value="1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="2">Country 2</option>   
</select>

<select disabled class="form-control" id="CityId" name="CityId"><option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>      
</select>
```

Now what I want to do is filter all of the cities based on the country selection,

here is the code I have so far

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {           

        //Variables
        var country = jQuery('#CountyId');
        var city = jQuery('#CityId'); 

        country.select2({
            placeholder: 'Select a country',
            width: '100%'         
        });
        country.on("select2:select", function (e) {              
             city.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        });

        city.select2({
            placeholder: 'Select a city',
            width: '100%',
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCity")',
                type: "get",
                data: { id: country.val() },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    return { results: data };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });          
    });
</script>
```

Now I have two issues

1: The `data` function on city needs to be evaluated only AFTER my country selection has been done.

2: Select 2 makes the ajax query when a user types in the search.  I just want to load the data set once, based on city selection and then do local text search?

ps: I am using `Select2 V4.0.3`